# how to write bytes array to text file in server in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to write bytes array to txt file on server code is running but it is not showing any contents on server file..
how do i write it

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Stream mystream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"LoadVideo;component/test.mp4", UriKind.Relative)).Stream;

    byte[] myarray = new byte[mystream.Length];
    int bytesRead = mystream.Read(myarray, 0, (int)mystream.Length);

    mystream.Close();

    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.OpenWriteCompleted += new OpenWriteCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenWriteCompleted);


    Uri u = new Uri("http://xyz/New.txt");
    wc.OpenWriteAsync(u, null, new object[] { myarray, bytesRead }); // Upload the file to the server
}

void wc_OpenWriteCompleted(object sender, OpenWriteCompletedEventArgs e) // The upload completed
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        // Upload completed without error
    }
}
```

Is my code correct? Please suggest any advice.

Comment: Please show some server code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use socket. Here is an example:
[WP7 socket tutorial](http://www.pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/Windows-Phone-7-Mango-Sockets.aspx)